# ffmpeg filter for accumulating pixel values

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, accumulate

I try to find an ffmpeg filter that accumulates consecutive pixel values iteratively. Basically just adding the pixel value of the current input frame to the same pixel in the previous output frame.

The closest approximation I've found so far is a tmix filter with a large number of frames (and weights and scale set to accumulate). But this gives only a running sum not a total sum (and its awfully slow).

Is there any easy or tricky way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think ffmpeg is the right tool for this task. I can show you a pretty straight forward way in Python if it's an option for you.

Comment: Well, (1) I would need the accumulated pixel value as input in another ffmpeg filter and (2) at least at first glance the required functionality seems similar to existing functionality so I hoped for some clever way to get there.
So thanks for the offer but a python solution wouldn't help me (unless one could integrate it into an ffmpeg filter-chain).

Comment: You are going to run into clipping. 8-bit pixels can store values 0 to 255. Unless a pixel is consistently very dark, the sum will reach beyond 255 within some frames. That said, look at lagfun filter.

Comment: The pixels are "dark" (actually its not normal pixels but the result of a tblend filter showing  difference)  and the potential clipping is exactly whats intended (thats the pixels I'd like to identify). Thank you for the hint, I will have a look.